# White space in footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For the life of me, I cannot tell where is my extra space coming from on my footer as you see it looks about near 20 30px on the url below

http://innovativeapps.dk/

But my footer code only has this so I don't understand where the extra space is coming from below my social icons.

```
footer {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's from `section#services`. `Padding: 50px 0`.

Comment: You should also mention that there are multiple sections with this ID, which causes severe headaches. (In this case, will affect multiple places on the screen where the padding changes.)

Answer (score 0):

section#services have a padding: 50px 0 you can change it with padding: 50px 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

@bartek_zet was faster than me ;)
Replace the section#services with this code.

```
section#services {
    float: left;
    padding: 50px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: its still their @Jean-Baptiste